# sql like operator on integer

Tags: mysql, sql

I google search 'sql like operator on integer', all tell me to use

```
   where cast ( int_field as text ) like '%30.%'
```

Warning:  reality is opposite position!!!

why I can use 'like' operator on integer, decimal, directly, without cast?

here is my mysql example:

[image]

another example:

[image]

integer type

[image]

Comment: I've removed [[tag:sql-server]] as the above clearly states "MySQL Workbench", which is an IDE for MySQL. Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: "_why I can use 'like' operator on integer, decimal, directly, without cast?_" - good question. (And only the one(s) responsible can answer it...)

Comment: no, sql-server have same feature. oracle has same, please add oracle tag as well !!!!

Comment: But you aren't asking about SQL Server, @hoogw , you're clearly using MySQL, so SQL Server has **nothing** to do with your question. The fact that it *might* have similar behaviour is irrelevant.

Comment: The behaviour, however, is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on SQL Server.

Comment: Do you expect an answer to a problem? (Except the problem that you can do like on integers, without cast.)

Comment: No, the document, you provide has nothing to say about like on integer, it only say like operator, you document has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: Yes it does. Read the first paragraph again... *"If any one of the arguments isn't of character string data type, **the SQL Server Database Engine converts it to character string data type**, if it's possible."* Emphasis mine.

Comment: No. I expect the answer to explain why it happen while all document tells me NO, but Reality is YES.

Comment: Again, that is the documentation for SQL Server; the only reason I am here is because of said incorrect tag. You then disputed this, and I reconfirmed my actions, and cited the relevant documentation for the RDBMS my expertise is in. I cannot answer about MySQL as that is not my expertise.

Comment: YES, you find the answer.  Mysql, oracle, share the same thing on this.

Answer (score 1):

This is handled by an implicit type conversion in MySQL.

When you use a numeric type in a string context, i.e. comparing it to a string, then the numeric is implicitly converted to a string, then the comparison is evaluated. You don't need to use `CAST()` first.

This is documented for MySQL here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html

I don't know what references you found while googling. They could be describing the SQL implementation in a different RDBMS product. Implementations vary between vendors; not all SQL databases have the same behavior.

For example, MySQL doesn't even support `CAST(<expr> AS TEXT)`. You can `CAST(<expr> AS CHAR)` (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast). So the example you read was not even possible for MySQL.

Or it could be that you're reading an article or a tutorial written by someone with an incomplete understanding of SQL semantics.

In general, implicit type conversions are standard in SQL, so you should find similar behavior in similar implementations.

https://crate.io/docs/sql-99/en/latest/chapters/03.html says:

> ### Numeric Operations
>
> A number is compatible with, and comparable to, all other numbers –
> that is, all numbers are mutually comparable and mutually assignable.
> Numbers may not be directly compared with, or directly assigned to,
> any other  class, though **implicit type conversions can
> occur in expressions**, SELECTs, INSERTs, DELETEs and UPDATEs. Explicit
> numeric type conversions can be forced with the CAST operator.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

Credit give to "Larnu"  he found the document explain why this happen.

[image]

first paragraph again... "If any one of the arguments isn't of character string data type, the SQL Server Database Engine converts it to character string data type, if it's possible

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

This is important You can do that on all SQL engine, Microsoft SQL server, Oracle, MySQL,

Here is document on MySQL, someone must will find similar document on Oracle.

Credit to "Bill Karwin"

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like
[image]

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html

[image]